90's experimental British film exploring the UK
Has anybody heard of an experimental art film from England in the early 90's where there is just narration and footage of places around the UK?
The narrator is recounting things that his travel companion said as they visited each place, but it is as though he is reading from a book or a diary. You are never shown either of them and there are no actors whatsoever in the film.
As far as I remember the film is full length and has a mans name in the title. The man's name is the name of the narrator's friend. The name MIGHT be Jonathan. The narrator goes into great historical and factual detail about each place in the film.
Some of the facts are sort of boring like how many boats a port builds each year, what tonnage of coal it takes in etc.
My best guess is it was made around 1992.
It's a really unusual film but it was awesome!

The answer is Robinson in Space (1997) by Patrick Keiller.

Robinson is commissioned to investigate the unspecified "problem of England." The narrator describes his seven excursions, with the unseen Robinson, around the country. They mainly concentrate on ports, power stations, prisons, and manufacturing plants, but they also bring in various literary connections, as well as a few conventional landscapes.

